# How can I see this .json file in the browser instead of downloading it?

Tags: ajax, json

My desired outcome is to get air quality data on my [web app](http://codepen.io/Mathieu-Roy/pen/xGWxZz?editors=001).

I'm trying to use the airnowapi API to obtain the data. I use an URL they provided [here](http://airnowapi.org/CurrentObservationsByLatLon/query), but my code fails to retrieve the data.

Here's a sample code of what I'm trying to do.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/latLong/current/?format=application/json&latitude=38.3651&longitude=-114.4141&distance=250&API_KEY=[API-KEY]",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {console.log(data);},
    error: function(){console.log("fail");}
});
```

It logs "fail" instead of logging the data. How can I remedy to that?

When I copy-paste the url in my browser, it downloads the .json file correctly, but I was expecting seeing it directly in the browser instead. I'm not sure if this is the origin of the problem.

Thank you!

PS.: This is my first time posting.

Comment: You don't need it to appear in your browser. I think the real cause of problem is `dataType jsonp` is unkown to jquery

Comment: Does the API support JSONP ?

Comment: @Kilanny JSONP is a valid datatype. see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Sirko hmmm, it supports JSON, but I'm not sure if it supports JSONP. How would I retrieve the data with JSON?

Comment: @MathieuRoy If you want to retrieve JSON directly to you (client-side) app, their server has to send the appropriator cross origin headers. You should check that first.

Comment: @Sirko ok I will search that, thank you!